# Print number in engineering format

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal

I am trying to print a number into engineering format with python, but I cannot seem to get it to work. The syntax SEEMS simple enough, but it just doesn't work.

```
>>> import decimal 
>>> x = decimal.Decimal(1000000)
>>> print x
1000000
>>>> print x.to_eng_string() 
1000000
```

I cannot figure out why this is. The two values are not equal (one is a string, the other is an int). Setting various contexts in `decimal` doesn't seem to help either. Any clues or ideas?

Comment: I found the solution here "%.4g" % x

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get this to work, you have to normalize the decimal first:

```
>>> x = decimal.Decimal ('10000000')

>>> x.normalize()
Decimal('1E+7')

>>> x.normalize().to_eng_string()
'10E+6'
```

---

The reason for this can be discovered by delving in to the source code.

If you examine `to_eng_string()` in the Python 2.7.3 source tree (`Lib/decimal.py` from the gzipped source tar ball [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/)), it simply calls `__str__` with `eng` set to true.

You can then see that it decides on how many digits go to the left of the decimal initially with:

```
leftdigits = self._exp + len(self._int)
```

The following table shows what the values are for those two things:

```
                         ._exp       ._int         len   leftdigits
                         -----       ---------     ---   ----------
Decimal (1000000)            0       '1000000'       7            7
Decimal ('1E+6')             6       '1'             1            7
```

The code that continues after that is:

```
if self._exp <= 0 and leftdigits > -6:
    # no exponent required
    dotplace = leftdigits
elif not eng:
    # usual scientific notation: 1 digit on left of the point
    dotplace = 1
elif self._int == '0':
    # engineering notation, zero
    dotplace = (leftdigits + 1) % 3 - 1
else:
    # engineering notation, nonzero
    dotplace = (leftdigits - 1) % 3 + 1
```

and you can see that, unless it already *has* an exponent in a certain range (`self._exp > 0 or leftdigits <= -6`), none will be given to it in the string representation.

---

Further investigation shows the reason for this behaviour. Looking at the code itself, you'll see it's based on the [`General Decimal Arithmetic Specification`](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html) (PDF [here](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.pdf)).

If you search that document for `to-scientific-string` (on which `to-engineering-string` is heavily based), it states in part (paraphrased, and with my bold bits):

> The "to-scientific-string" operation converts a number to a string, using scientific notation **if an exponent is needed.** The operation is not affected by the context.
>
> If the number is a finite number then:
>
> The coefficient is first converted to a string in base ten using the characters 0 through 9 with no leading zeros (except if its value is zero, in which case a single 0 character is used).
>
> Next, the adjusted exponent is calculated; this is the exponent, plus the number of characters in the converted coefficient, less one. That is, exponent+(clength-1), where clength is the length of the coefficient in decimal digits.
>
> **If the exponent is less than or equal to zero and the adjusted exponent is greater than or equal to -6, the number will be converted to a character form without using exponential notation.** In this case, if the exponent is zero then no decimal point is added. Otherwise (the exponent will be negative), a decimal point will be inserted with the absolute value of the exponent specifying the number of characters to the right of the decimal point. “0” characters are added to the left of the converted coefficient as necessary. If no character precedes the decimal point after this insertion then a conventional “0” character is prefixed.

In other words, it's doing what it's doing because that's what the standard tells it to do.

Comment: Why would it bother to check that? I asked it for something specific. It then decided that I didn't want that and wanted just what I gave it? Python confuses me at times...

Comment: @jmurrayufo, check the update. Basically, it's doing that because that's what the standard tells it to do.

Comment: Here it is in one line: `print(decimal.Decimal(str(my_number)).normalize().to_eng_string())`.

Answer (score 19):

I realize that this is an old thread, but it does come near the top of a search for `python engineering notation`.

I am an engineer who likes the "engineering 101" engineering units.  I don't even like designations such as `0.1uF`, I want that to read `100nF`.  I played with the `Decimal` class and didn't really like its behavior over the range of possible values, so I rolled a package called `engineering_notation` that is pip-installable.

```
pip install engineering_notation
```

From within Python:

```
>>> from engineering_notation import EngNumber
>>> EngNumber('1000000')
1M
>>> EngNumber(1000000)
1M
>>> EngNumber(1000000.0)
1M
>>> EngNumber('0.1u')
100n
>>> EngNumber('1000m')
1
```

This package also supports comparisons and other simple numerical operations.

https://github.com/slightlynybbled/engineering_notation

Answer (score 7):

There is a solution using the built-in [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

I will assume that (forward in time) you now use the built-in python 3, as all things formatting are greatly simplifed and normalized (I recommend to bookmark [this cheat sheet](https://pyformat.info).

```py
In [1]: myfloat = 0.000000001
In [2]: print(f'{myfloat:g}')
1e-09
```

the older syntax (which would work with python 2) is:

```py
In [17]: '%g' % myfloat
Out[17]: '1e-09'
```

Another nice format is given by:

```py
In [3]: print(f'{myfloat:E}')
1.000000E-09
```

for which you ccan have some control over the output:

```py
In [4]: print(f'{myfloat:.3E}')
1.000E-09
```

Comment: That's scientific notation, not engineering notation. With engineering notation, the exponent is always a multiple of 3.

Comment: I was not aware of that distinction. Do you allow me to add it to my answer @Waxrat ?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that you're going to have to roll your own:

```
from math import log10
def eng_str(x):
    y = abs(x)
    exponent = int(log10(y))
    engr_exponent = exponent - exponent%3
    z = y/10**engr_exponent
    sign = '-' if x < 0 else ''
    return sign+str(z)+'e'+str(engr_exponent)
```

Although you may want to take a little more care in the formatting of the `z` portion...

*not well tested.  Feel free to edit if you find bugs*

Comment: While I don't mind the idea, I am more curious why the `decimal` class doesn't do what it seems it should, or how I am using it wrong

Comment: @jmurrayufo -- Sorry, I suppose I misunderstood the question :).

Answer (score 2):

matplotlib can be used also:

```
>>> from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter
>>> engFormat = EngFormatter()
>>> print(engFormat(1000))
1 k
```

I let you take a look for further details and options at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html
Another more complex example:

```
>>> from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter
>>> engFormat = EngFormatter(unit='Hz',places=2,sep='')
>>> print(engFormat(1000))
1.00kHz
```

Answer (score 1):

[QuantiPhy](https://quantiphy.readthedocs.io) is another package that can help you with this. *QuantiPhy* provides the *Quantity* class that is used to combine a value and units into one object. It can format the quantity in a variety of ways. Generally people use SI scale factors, but engineering form is also supported. Install with:

```
pip3 install quantiphy
```

You can create a *Quantity* object starting from a number or a string:

```
>>> from quantiphy import Quantity
>>> q = Quantity(10000000)
>>> q.render(form='eng')
'10e6'
```

By default *QuantiPhy* uses SI notation, but you can set the default form to 'eng':

```
>>> print(q)
10M
>>> Quantity.set_prefs(form='eng')
>>> print(q)
10e6
```

Normally you would specify units to a quantity:

```
>>> f = Quantity(10_000_000, 'Hz')
>>> print(f)
10e6 Hz
```

*Quantity* subclasses *float*, so you can use a quantity anywhere you would use a float.

*QuantiPhy* is a powerful package that is well supported and well documented. I encourage you to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (I had the same problem)
It's shallow thought, no fancy programming,
quick and dirty, but fine for me :).
It has a quick test included.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    converts float number to string in engineering form
    xxx.xxx [G M k _ m u n p]
    
"""

def F(f):

    if f < 0.0:
        sgn = "-"# = True
        f = -f
    else:
        sgn = "+"
    
    if   f > 999999999999.999999999999:
        return sgn+"max.---"+">" # "overflow error"
    elif f > 999999999.999999999999:
        v = f/1000000000, "G"
    elif f > 999999.999999999999:
        v = f/1000000.0, "M"
    elif f > 999.999999999999:
        v = f/1000.0, "k"
    elif f > 0.999999999999:
        v = f , " "
    elif f > 0.000999999999:
        v = f*1000 , "m"
    elif f > 0.000000999999:
        v = f*1000000.0 , "u"
    elif f > 0.000000000999:
        v = f*1000000000.0 , "n"
    elif f > 0.000000000000999:
        v = f*1000000000000.0 , "p"
    elif f > 0.000000000000000999:
        v = f*1000000000000.0 , "p"
    else:
        return sgn+"min.---"+"<" # "underflow error"
        
    n = v[0]
    if sgn == "-":
        n = - n
        
    # to sIII.FFF s = sign, I = integer digit, F = fractional digit
    
    n = "{:+08.3f}".format(n)
    return n + v[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test
    s = ""
    f = 0.0000000000000001111111111
    for a in range(55):
        f = f * 3.333
        v = F(f)
        print("{:03d} {:-37.18f}".format(a,f),v)
        v = F(-f)
        print("{:03d} {:-37.18f}".format(a,-f),v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like `Decimal(s).normalize().to_eng_string()` but the latter does not use engineering notation for e-3 and e-6.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def to_eng(v: float | str | Decimal) -> str:
    """
    Convert a floating point value to engineering notation.
    """
    dec = Decimal(v).normalize().as_tuple()
    sign = '-' if dec.sign else ''
    digits = ''.join(str(digit) for digit in dec.digits)
    exp = dec.exponent

    # number of digits to left of decimal point
    leftdigits = exp + len(digits)

    dotplace = (leftdigits - 1) % 3 + 1

    if dotplace <= 0:
        intpart = '0'
        fracpart = '.' + '0' * -dotplace + digits
    elif dotplace >= len(digits):
        intpart = digits + '0' * (dotplace - len(digits))
        fracpart = ''
    else:
        intpart = digits[:dotplace]
        fracpart = '.' + digits[dotplace:]
    if leftdigits == dotplace:
        exps = ''
    else:
        exps = f'e{leftdigits - dotplace}'

    return sign + intpart + fracpart + exps
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a python package called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which can accomplish this and other scientific formatting goals.

```
pip install sciform
```

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(exp_mode="engineering")
print(sform(1e7))
# 10e+06
```

Another example showing some more features:

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    exp_mode="engineering",
    exp_format="prefix",
)

num = 3141592.7
unc = 1618

print(sform(num, unc))
# (3.1416 ± 0.0016) M
```

Here we see that we can format value/uncertainty pairs in addition to just values. We can also convert standard ascii exponents like `e+06` into SI prefixes like `M` (short for Mega). We also utilize a standard algorithm to round the uncertainty to one or two decimal places and to round the value to the same decimal place as the uncertainty -- the so-called [particle data group (PDG)](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#particle-data-group-significant-figures) rounding rules.

Answer (score -5):

It is 2020 now folks! and there is an COVID-19 pandemic. You got to use f-string literals for this type of work:

With python3.6.4 and above, you can do

```py
a = 3e-4
print(f"{a:.0E}")
```

Comment: Note that this returns scientific notation, not engineering notation where E should be in multiples of 3. Question isn't totally clear on whether this is acceptable or not, but it is important in many use-cases.

Comment: I saw your answer after I posted mine, sorry for the overlap. In CS, the definition of "engineering notation" is that given in this answer - perhaps the OP was making a confusion, but this answer is not.