# Convert float number to string with engineering notation (with SI prefix) in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers

I have a float number such as `x=23392342.1`

I would like to convert it to a string with engineering notation (with metric prefix)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

So in my example 23392342.1 = 23.3923421E6 = 23.3923421 M (mega)

I would like to display `23.3923421 M`

Comment: Please tell us how you would approach your problem and why you think that your idea is not optimal or which part of your idea you can't implement.

Comment: I think I will need a dict to store every metric prefix. I will probably calculate log10 to find the "nearest" exponent which is multiple of 3 (but except for da, h,) ... but this not so trivial... (because of this exceptions)... I also wondering if there is no STANDARD way with Python to achieve such a task because I want to manage every possible metric prefix

Comment: Also see, [`pint`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a function inspired from [Formatting a number with a metric prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181024/formatting-a-number-with-a-metric-prefix?rq=1)

`metric.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math


def to_si(d, sep=' '):
    """
    Convert number to string with SI prefix

    :Example:

    >>> to_si(2500.0)
    '2.5 k'

    >>> to_si(2.3E6)
    '2.3 M'

    >>> to_si(2.3E-6)
    '2.3 µ'

    >>> to_si(-2500.0)
    '-2.5 k'

    >>> to_si(0)
    '0'

    """

    inc_prefixes = ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y']
    dec_prefixes = ['m', 'µ', 'n', 'p', 'f', 'a', 'z', 'y']

    if d == 0:
        return str(0)

    degree = int(math.floor(math.log10(math.fabs(d)) / 3))

    prefix = ''

    if degree != 0:
        ds = degree / math.fabs(degree)
        if ds == 1:
            if degree - 1 < len(inc_prefixes):
                prefix = inc_prefixes[degree - 1]
            else:
                prefix = inc_prefixes[-1]
                degree = len(inc_prefixes)

        elif ds == -1:
            if -degree - 1 < len(dec_prefixes):
                prefix = dec_prefixes[-degree - 1]
            else:
                prefix = dec_prefixes[-1]
                degree = -len(dec_prefixes)

        scaled = float(d * math.pow(1000, -degree))

        s = "{scaled}{sep}{prefix}".format(scaled=scaled,
                                           sep=sep,
                                           prefix=prefix)

    else:
        s = "{d}".format(d=d)

    return s


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

and its usage:

```
from metric import to_si
d = 23392342.1
print(to_si(d))
```

It will display

```
23.3923421 M
```

Comment: Parameter needs testing for zero as [log10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is undefined, resulting in `ValueError: math domain error`. E.g. :
````
  if d == 0.0:
    degree = 0
  else:
    degree = int(...
````

Comment: I dumped this into an extended `int` class's `__str__` method so it can be used in string formatting output. https://gist.github.com/thorsummoner/aed154cbba0cf9f61182 Example: `import metric; print('>> %s' % metric.MetricInt(2**16));`

Comment: really love your function!

Comment: for the missing NaN support see https://stackoverflow.com/a/944733/7809404

Answer (score 8):

Use the [QuantiPhy](https://quantiphy.readthedocs.io/en/stable) package. It is a stable well documented and well supported package that is designed to do just what you want.

```
>>> from quantiphy import Quantity

>>> v = Quantity(23.3923421E6)                                               
>>> str(v)                                                                   
'23.392M'                                                                    

>>> v.render(prec='full')                                                    
'23.3923421M'
```

Generally people use SI unit prefixes with units, and Quantity is designed to combine the units with the number.

```
>>> v = Quantity(23.3923421E6, 'V')
>>> print(v)
23.392 MV

>>> f = Quantity('23.3923421 MHz')
>>> print('{}'.format(f))
23.392 MHz
```

Quantity subclasses float, so you can use quantities in expressions as you would a float:

```
>>> t = 1/f                                                                  
>>> print(t)                                                                 
4.274903281275114e-08

>>> t = Quantity(t, 's')                                                     
>>> print(t)
42.749 ns
```

Answer (score 5):

A direct solution is to use the [Decimal.to_eng_string](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.to_eng_string) method and then do a dictionary lookup to convert the exponent to appropriate metric prefix.

Comment: How do you get exponent value ? you will have to parse string !!

Comment: There are two related questions that could be considered duplicates and should be linked (automatically?). The first uses your solution ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311148/print-number-in-engineering-format ). A duplicate also shows an approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985438/print-numbers-in-terms-of-engineering-units-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prefixed](https://pypi.org/project/prefixed/) which has a float type with additional formatting options.

```py
>>> from prefixed import Float

>>> x = Float(23392342.1)
>>> print(f'{x:!h}')
23.392342 M
```

Or if you want to keep 7 decimal places

```
>>> print(f'{x:!.7h}')
23.3923421 M
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method with no dependencies:

```
def to_units(x_):
    units = {-12: "T",-9: "G",-6: "M",-3: "K",0: "",3: "m",6: "µ",9: "n",12: "p",15: "f"}
    k = -12
    while x_ * 10.0**k < 1: 
        k += 3
    return f"{x_*10.0**k}{units[k]}"
```

Example:

```
for i in range(-15,15):
    print(f"{to_units(1*10.0**i)} \t {1*10.0**i:1,.15f}")

1.0f    0.000000000000001
10.0f   0.000000000000010
100.0f  0.000000000000100
1.0p    0.000000000001000
10.0p   0.000000000010000
100.0p  0.000000000100000
1.0n    0.000000001000000
10.0n   0.000000010000000
100.0n  0.000000100000000
1.0µ    0.000001000000000
10.0µ   0.000010000000000
100.0µ  0.000100000000000
1.0m    0.001000000000000
10.0m   0.010000000000000
100.0m  0.100000000000000
1.0     1.000000000000000
10.0    10.000000000000000
100.0   100.000000000000000
1.0K    1,000.000000000000000
10.0K   10,000.000000000000000
100.0K  100,000.000000000000000
1.0M    1,000,000.000000000000000
10.0M   10,000,000.000000000000000
100.0M  100,000,000.000000000000000
1.0G    1,000,000,000.000000000000000
10.0G   10,000,000,000.000000000000000
100.0G  100,000,000,000.000000000000000
1.0T    1,000,000,000,000.000000000000000
10.0T   10,000,000,000,000.000000000000000
100.0T  100,000,000,000,000.000000000000000
```

Comment: You need to add abs() around x_ in the loop, otherwise it will loop forever for negative numbers until python gives up (and throws OverflowError)

Comment: Also kilo should be small k

Answer (score 0):

I've written a PyPi package called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which supports this type of formatting (and many other scientific formatting options)

```
pip install sciform
```

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    exp_mode="engineering",
    exp_format="prefix",
)

x = 23392342.1
print(sform(x))
# 23.3923421 M

for exp in range(-30, +30+1):
    num = 10**exp
    num_str = sform(num)
    print(f'{num:.1e} => {num_str}')

# 1.0e-30 => 1 q
# 1.0e-29 => 10 q
# 1.0e-28 => 100 q
# 1.0e-27 => 1 r
# 1.0e-26 => 10 r
# 1.0e-25 => 100 r
# 1.0e-24 => 1 y
# 1.0e-23 => 10 y
# 1.0e-22 => 100 y
# 1.0e-21 => 1 z
# 1.0e-20 => 10 z
# 1.0e-19 => 100 z
# 1.0e-18 => 1 a
# 1.0e-17 => 10 a
# 1.0e-16 => 100 a
# 1.0e-15 => 1 f
# 1.0e-14 => 10 f
# 1.0e-13 => 100 f
# 1.0e-12 => 1 p
# 1.0e-11 => 10 p
# 1.0e-10 => 100 p
# 1.0e-09 => 1 n
# 1.0e-08 => 10 n
# 1.0e-07 => 100 n
# 1.0e-06 => 1 μ
# 1.0e-05 => 10 μ
# 1.0e-04 => 100 μ
# 1.0e-03 => 1 m
# 1.0e-02 => 10 m
# 1.0e-01 => 100 m
# 1.0e+00 => 1
# 1.0e+01 => 10
# 1.0e+02 => 100
# 1.0e+03 => 1 k
# 1.0e+04 => 10 k
# 1.0e+05 => 100 k
# 1.0e+06 => 1 M
# 1.0e+07 => 10 M
# 1.0e+08 => 100 M
# 1.0e+09 => 1 G
# 1.0e+10 => 10 G
# 1.0e+11 => 100 G
# 1.0e+12 => 1 T
# 1.0e+13 => 10 T
# 1.0e+14 => 100 T
# 1.0e+15 => 1 P
# 1.0e+16 => 10 P
# 1.0e+17 => 100 P
# 1.0e+18 => 1 E
# 1.0e+19 => 10 E
# 1.0e+20 => 100 E
# 1.0e+21 => 1 Z
# 1.0e+22 => 10 Z
# 1.0e+23 => 100 Z
# 1.0e+24 => 1 Y
# 1.0e+25 => 10 Y
# 1.0e+26 => 100 Y
# 1.0e+27 => 1 R
# 1.0e+28 => 10 R
# 1.0e+29 => 100 R
# 1.0e+30 => 1 Q
```

It also supports common SI prefixes that are not multiples of 3:

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    exp_mode="scientific",
    exp_format="prefix",
    add_small_si_prefixes=True,
)

for exp in range(-3, +3+1):
    num = 10**exp
    num_str = sform(num)
    print(f'{num:.1e} => {num_str}')

# 1.0e-03 => 1 m
# 1.0e-02 => 1 c
# 1.0e-01 => 1 d
# 1.0e+00 => 1
# 1.0e+01 => 1 da
# 1.0e+02 => 1 h
# 1.0e+03 => 1 k
```